# Fixed size priority queue

Tags: java, queue

I've tried implementing priority queue with fixed size in Java using `TreeSet` and overriding `add()` method:

```
public class FixedSizePriorityQueue<E> extends TreeSet<E> {
    private final int capacity;

    public FixedSizePriorityQueue(final int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public FixedSizePriorityQueue(
            final int capacity,
            final Comparator<? super E> comparator) {

        super(comparator);
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final E e) {
        // initialized with 0 or less than zero capacity
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // keep adding until we fill the queue
        if (size() < capacity) {
            return super.add(e);
        }

        if (comparator() != null
                && comparator().compare(this.last(), e) < 0) {
            pollLast();
            return super.add(e);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your thoughts, hints and comments.

Comment: Are you sure you want your `FixedSizePriorityQueue` be a `TreeSet`? Do you want to support all methods of a `TreeSet` ? I would internally use a `TreeSet` but not extend it.

Comment: @MrSmith42, good point! I don't need to extend it, I can use it internally. Tnx.

Comment: What's the usage of `pollLast()` method in `add` method?

Comment: @tintinmj the idea is to have fixed size priority queue, and with `pollLast()`, I remove the most irrelevant element and add new one, using `super.add()`, leaving super to prioritize.

Answer (score 3):

Two thoughts:

1. If there is other code and you need all the features of a TreeSet great, otherwise delegate to a TreeSet member variable.
2. Your code `if (capacity <= 0)` is somewhat superfluous because of the next test `if (size() < capacity)`

Comment: thanks for noticing `if (capacity <= 0)`. `size()` will always return 0 or greater than 0 :)

Answer (score -1):

I rarely check the return of add methods. I would suggest throwing an exception to indicate the container is full. 
Add methods that return available space and full state.

Comment: I didn't downvote on this answer, but this is not what I would consider a "proper" review.  Look at some other answers on this site, get a feel for what they should look like, and then come back with that knowledge and integrate it into your answer.

Comment: @syb0rg How is this not a proper review? (This answer was recently flagged, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: @SimonForsberg It seemed better served as a comment, and I still believe it would be.  There isn't enough content in my opinion.  Why doesn't the OP check the return of add methods, there is no reason given nor a link to point me to evidence?  Would one throw a custom exception, or a standard library exception, and why?  Where is the benefit in adding functions that return available space and full state, and how would that be used to refine the code in the question?  Now for you and I, these questions are well known.  But I think newcomers need more explanation than what was supplied here.

Comment: @syb0rg That arguably makes it a bad answer, not "not an answer". Short answers are fine.